# Embed a custom UWP control in ATL ActiveX control

Tags: c++, uwp, com, activex, atl

Is there a way to somehow Embed a UWP custom control in ATL ActiveX control?
I want to use the AdaptiveCards in one of my ActiveX control.

I found that I can [use the UWP XAML hosting API in a C++ Win32 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-xaml-hosting-api)
I tried to use the [sample project](https://github.com/marb2000/XamlIslands/tree/master/1903_Samples/CppWinRT_Win32_App) as start project

1. I added the ATL support to the project and it compiled without errors.
2. but it gives me the following errors after adding IDL file to define an interface.

Error   MIDL2003    [msg]redefinition [context]: IUnknown
Error   MIDL2003    [msg]redefinition [context]: _FLAGGED_WORD_BLOB

Comment: Any chance you resolved this?